# facing with an error in vue.js "Property or method "step1_category" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: html, vue.js

here i am facing this error. "Property or method "step1_category" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property." where I am going wrong please tell me.

```
<template id="step1" v-if="currentStep == 1">
    <strong class="progress_bar1"></strong>
    <h1 class="post_adttl">Post Ad</h1>

    <p><input style="width: 93%;" type="text" class="vuepost_ad" placeholder="Search your category"
              name="category" @change="go"
              v-model="step1_category" maxlength="200" id="id_post_type"></p>

    <p><input placeholder="Title" class="vuepost_ad" type="text" name="title" v-model="step1_title"
              maxlength="60" id="id_post_title"></p>

    <p class="select_p">
        <input type="text" class="vuepost_ad" placeholder="Address" name="address" v-model="step1_address"
               maxlength="200" id="id_post_address">
        <input type="text" class="vuepost_ad" placeholder="City" name="city" v-model="step1_city"
               maxlength="100" id="id_post_city">
    </p>

    <p class="select_p">
        <input type="text" class="vuepost_ad" placeholder="State" name="state" v-model="step1_state"
               maxlength="100" id="id_post_state">
        <input type="text" class="vuepost_ad" placeholder="Zip" name="zip" v-model="step1_Zip" maxlength="50"
               id="id_post_zip">
    </p>

    <p><input style="width: 93%;" type="number" class="vuepost_ad" placeholder="Price" name="price"
              v-model="step1_price"
              step="any"
              id="id_post_price"></p>
    <p><textarea name="description" v-model="step1_description" class="vuepost_ad"
                 placeholder="Ad description.." rows="5" maxlength="600" id="id_post_description"></textarea>

        <button type="button" @click.prevent="goToStep(2)">Next</button>
</template>
```

**vue.js**

```
Vue.component('step1', {
template: '#step1',
props: [
'currentStep',
'step1'
]
});


var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
currentStep: 1,
step1: {
step1_category: '',
step1_title: '',
step1_address: '',
step1_city:'',
step1_state:'',
step1_Zip:'',
step1_price:'',
step1_description:'',
},
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your data you have it set to `step1.step1_category`. Bind your `v-model` to that and it will work. You will need to do this for *all* data properties within this `step1` object in your `data`.